# Convert text to other format

Tags: javascript

So i have an input field which gives the value "2020-03-10". I need to convert this to "10-03-2020". I don't even need it to be a date, just a value is okay.

I feel like it is really easy, but I still can't find it with my search queries on here and google :p

`<input type="text" id="search-text"/>`

Comment: Take a look to moment.js https://momentjs.com you can do that an much more with dates using this library...

Comment: I think what you want is an input mask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```js
const value = '2020-03-10'
const formatted = value.split('-').reverse().join('-');
console.log(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("search-text").value = "2020-03-10"
console.log(document.getElementById("search-text").value.split('-').reverse().join('-'))
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search-text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split it with '-'. Then put it back together in the order you want. With JavaScript:

```
function conv(t) {
  var mySplit = t.split('-');
  return mySplit[2] + '-' + mySplit[1] + '-' + mySplit[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex replace and reorder

```js
let yyyymmdd ='2020-03-10';
const  ddmmyyyy = yyyymmdd.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/,"$3-$2-$1")
console.log(ddmmyyyy);
```

Regex and destruct match:

```js
let yyyymmdd ='2020-03-10';
const  [_,yyyy,mm,dd] = yyyymmdd.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/);
const ddmmyyyy = `${dd}-${mm}-${yyyy}`;
console.log(ddmmyyyy);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this:

You can use `.split('-')` to find all occurrences of `-` and split the elements to an array and then use `.reverse()` to change the sequence of the elements in array and finally use `.join('-')` to convert your array into string separating each element of the string with `-`

```
const str = '2020-03-10';
let newStr = str.split('-').reverse().join('-');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lekv7jxu/

--- Edit

You can also make use of arrow functions to create a function and make the code drier

```
const str = '2020-03-10';
let newStr = str => str.split('-').reverse().join('-');
```

Comment: @mplungjan oh, I didn't notice your solution

Comment: @mplungjan declaring a function instead of using `let`, so it can be reuseable..

Answer (score 0):

More universal approach. Converting start when blur input

```js
const dateInput = document.querySelector('input#dateAsText');

console.assert(typeof dataInput === 'undefined', {
  msg: 'Not find input'
});

dateInput.addEventListener('change', formateDate);

function formateDate(e) {
  const date = new Date(e.target.value);
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]') {
    e.target.value = `${date.getDate()}-${(date.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, 0)}-${date.getFullYear()}`;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="dateAsText">
```

Comment: `const date = new Date(e.target.value); if (!isNaN(date)) ...`